# How to obtain ETag for individual document when using FeedResponse from Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm looking at samples from https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/dc3468bd5ce828e504ddef92ef792c35370de055/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ItemManagement/Program.cs#L590

Here is the example of using ETag when using container.ReadItemAsync:

```
            ItemResponse<SalesOrder> itemResponse = await container.ReadItemAsync<SalesOrder>(
                partitionKey: new PartitionKey("Account1"),
                id: "SalesOrder1");

            Console.WriteLine("ETag of read item - {0}", itemResponse.ETag);

            SalesOrder item = itemResponse;
            //Update the total due
            itemResponse.Resource.TotalDue = 1000000;

            //persist the change back to the server
            ItemResponse<SalesOrder> updatedDoc = await container.ReplaceItemAsync<SalesOrder>(
                partitionKey: new PartitionKey(item.AccountNumber),
                id: item.Id,
                item: item);

            Console.WriteLine("ETag of item now that is has been updated - {0}", updatedDoc.ETag);

            //now, using the originally retrieved item do another update 
            //but set the AccessCondition class with the ETag of the originally read item and also set the AccessConditionType
            //this tells the service to only do this operation if ETag on the request matches the current ETag on the item
            //in our case it won't, because we updated the item and therefore gave it a new ETag
            try
            {
                itemResponse.Resource.TotalDue = 9999999;
                updatedDoc = await container.ReplaceItemAsync<SalesOrder>(itemResponse, item.Id, new PartitionKey(item.AccountNumber), new ItemRequestOptions { IfMatchEtag = itemResponse.ETag });
            }
            catch (CosmosException cre)
            {
                //   now notice the failure when attempting the update 
                //   this is because the ETag on the server no longer matches the ETag of doc (b/c it was changed in step 2)
                if (cre.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("As expected, we have a pre-condition failure exception\n");
                }
            }
```

In my scenario I have a query and I need to obtain ETag for later use in Update. In this sample we get `FeedResponse<SalesOrder>` which has ETag, but this is the tag associated with last transaction, not document. So my question is how to get ETag of an individual document?

```
        private static async Task QueryItems()
        {
            //******************************************************************************************************************
            // 1.4 - Query for items by a property other than Id
            //
            // NOTE: Operations like AsEnumerable(), ToList(), ToArray() will make as many trips to the database
            //       as required to fetch the entire result-set. Even if you set MaxItemCount to a smaller number. 
            //       MaxItemCount just controls how many results to fetch each trip. 
            //******************************************************************************************************************
            Console.WriteLine("\n1.4 - Querying for a item using its AccountNumber property");

            QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition(
                "select * from sales s where s.AccountNumber = @AccountInput ")
                .WithParameter("@AccountInput", "Account1");

            FeedIterator<SalesOrder> resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<SalesOrder>(
                query,
                requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
                {
                    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("Account1"),
                    MaxItemCount = 1
                });

            List<SalesOrder> allSalesForAccount1 = new List<SalesOrder>();
            while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
            {
                FeedResponse<SalesOrder> response = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync();
                SalesOrder sale = response.First();
                Console.WriteLine($"\n1.4.1 Account Number: {sale.AccountNumber}; Id: {sale.Id};");
                if(response.Diagnostics != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($" Diagnostics {response.Diagnostics.ToString()}");
                }

                allSalesForAccount1.Add(sale);
            }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a better way at handling this scenario?

Comment: @WBuck, No, but I haven't actively looked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for now. Not perfect as I call `JObject.ToObject<T>` twice for:

- **SalesOrder** - business object
- **ETagCosmosDocument** - object with ETag

```
public class ETagCosmosDocument
{
    public string _etag {get; set;}
}

public class CosmosDocument<T>
{
    public T Document {get; private set;}
    public string ETag {get; private set;}

    public CosmosDocument(T document, string etag)
    {
        Document = document;
        ETag = etag;
    }

    public static implicit operator CosmosDocument<T> (JObject o)
    {
        T document = o.ToObject<T>();
        ETagCosmosDocument etagDoc = o.ToObject<ETagCosmosDocument>();

        return new CosmosDocument<T>(document, etagDoc._etag);
     }
}
```

then using `FeedIterator<dynamic>` instead of `FeedIterator<SalesOrder>`

```
QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition(...)

FeedIterator<dynamic> resultSet = container.GetItemQueryIterator<dynamic>(
                query,
                requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
                {
                    PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("Account1"),
                    MaxItemCount = 1
                });

while (resultSet.HasMoreResults)
{   
    FeedResponse<dynamic> response = await resultSet.ReadNextAsync();

    JObject r = response.First();
    CosmosDocument<SalesOrder> cd = r;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you execute a query, the FeedResponse contains a list of objects of type T. You can obtain the ETag if the T contains a property that matches with the `_etag` system property. [Source Github issue comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/3552#issuecomment-1307788114).

For instance, using NewtonSoft.JSON's `JsonProperty` attribute, I had to add the following property to my type `T`

```
[JsonProperty("_etag")]
public string ETag { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -2):

The etag is a property of the response object. Can get it this way.

```
string etag = response.ETag;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at docs https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedresponse-1?view=azure-dotnet
FeedResponse can have multiple results. And ETag definition states that "Gets the entity tag associated with last transaction in the Azure Cosmos DB service". So will all documents have the same ETag?

I tested this and I get response.ETag = null

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Yes, the answer above is correct. Use dynamic for your feediterator and response and you can see the etag and other system properties.

Comment: Etag is null...